# Javascript API Request

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm trying to get the data from this API and show it on my website :

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=XTZ&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR&api_key=e5e88b327eb7dbaa1e16e1cd35ed5148b5ac9a8563aa610ae615958868c79a61

You can find below my code but I'm not able to make it work (My website is not showing the result). I think my issue is due to the fact that the data are store in a kind of table :
I tried to use a table "data[0].XTZ.BTC" to get the first data but doesn't help.

```
// Price 
// Cycle Stackexchange - Not Working
 const ul3 = document.getElementById('Price');
  const url3 = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=XTZ&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR&api_key=e5e88b327eb7dbaa1e16e1cd35ed5148b5ac9a8563aa610ae615958868c79a61';
  fetch(url3)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data){
    if (data.length > 0) {
      let span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = `${data[0].XTZ.BTC}`;
      ul3.appendChild(span)
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I also used this code to get another API and this one works perfectly

```
// Cycle - Working
const app = document.getElementById('root')

const container = document.createElement('div')
container.setAttribute('class', 'container')

app.appendChild(container)

var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', 'https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/rolls_history/tz1NortRftucvAkD1J58L32EhSVrQEWJCEnB?number=1&page=0', true)
request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(movie => {

      const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
      h1.textContent = movie.cycle

      container.appendChild(h1)

    })
  } else {
    const errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee')
    errorMessage.textContent = `Gah, it's not working!`
    app.appendChild(errorMessage)
  }
}

request.send()
```

My goal is to get the price in BTC, EUR, and USD.
You can find here the Codepen where I tried different code to get the price :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMXeYJ

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Define "not able to make it work". Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Unrelated, but not sure why you'd need string interpolation here.

Comment: @Dave Newton, first thank you for your answer,
I'm not able to get the data from this API and display it on my website.
I used a code find online and try to adapt it to my use case
[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMXeYJ)

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "It's [not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)" is not a clear problem statement, and your question should include a [mcve] *in the question itself* (not just a link to codepen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API return this result :

```
result = {"XTZ":{"BTC":0.0001705,"USD":0.678,"EUR":0.5957}}
```

So the path to access USD for example is :

```
console.log(result["XTZ"]["USD"]);
// output : 0.678
```

or because it is an object

```
console.log(result.XTZ.USD);
// output : 0.678
```

Function corrected :

```
function(data){
  if (data && data.XTZ) {
     let span = document.createElement('span');
     span.innerHTML = data.XTZ.BTC;
     ul3.appendChild(span)
  }
}
```